Turn on camera led on pi 0 2w
i tried to use disable_camera_led=0 in /boot/config.txt file but it didn't work, and as for the camera its brand new pi camera v2
i went through the post where its been told that camera led line is been removed
topic: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=328635
but i like it to be turn on. is there anyway to turn on
